# assertarrayequals

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4

I am testing two arrays in Junit 4 to see if they are equal and get the error:

> arrays first differed at element [0]; expected:
>   com.scheduling.Process<(Background, 1000)> but was:
>   com.scheduling.Process<(Background, 1000)>

I know this is very little information to go on. I have read elsewhere that `assertArrayEquals` looks at references within the array.

Should something like `assertArrayEquals(new Cat(), new Cat())` return equal (given that the `Cat` class implements comparable)? Or will `assertArrayEquals` deem the two `Cat` objects different as they are not linked by a reference?

Comment: Well does your `Process` class override `equals`? (Looking at the code, it seems that it *should* call `equals` rather than just comparing references...)

Comment: @Jon Skeet, what would I do without you ... I had naively only implemented comparable ..thanks a mil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It compares using `equals`. You can check that by running

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals(new Object[]{new Integer(1)}, new Object[]{new Integer(1)});
```

Or by creating a class that just implements the method `equals`.

Even though the two objects are different instances, the arrays still compare correctly.